# Problem with nviz and QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis, sextante-qgis-plugin, nviz

I am using QGIS 1.8.0 on Windows 7. 
In nviz (via SEXTANTE), after selecting an altitude layer and the GRASS region extent, I hit OK; the progress bar quickly reaches 100% and then absolutely nothing happens. I tried loading other layers, including additional vector ones and changing the extent.
I have also reinstalled QGIS using OSGeo4W, cleaned the registries and reinstalled the plugin. What am I missing?